# Text input gets gap when zooming out in 90%, 67%, 33%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem with a textbox input, when the user zoom out the page, this textbox gets outside its div, but curiously it only happens when zoom is 90%, 67%,33%... The textbox looks just fine when zoom is 100%, 75%, 50%.
My css class looks like this:

```css
    #someDropdown .someTextbox {
      margin-left: -24px; 
      background: #fff; 
      margin-top: -5px; 
      padding-left: 25px;
      width: 100%;

      zoom:1;
      -ms-transform: scale(1); /* IE 9 */
      -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
      -moz-transform: scale(1); /* Firefox */
      -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
      -o-transform: scale(1); /* Opera */
      -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1); /* Safari And Chrome */
      -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
      transform: scale(1); /* Standard Property */
      transform-origin: 0 0;  /* Standard Property */
    }
```

[image: The image is zoomed in 90%]

so, I wonder if there is any way to correct this behavior, I also tried with "position: fixed" however the textbox gets at left/top and that is not the proper behavior I'm looking for.

Comment: without any HTML to attach this css too it will be tough to duplicate this

Comment: Why are you applying `scale(1)` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I used the `scale(1)` To try to avoid that it looks different through browsers, -it has happened to me before-, however i could solve it with some other css like this one:

```
#someDropdown .someTextbox {
      margin-left: -24px;
      margin-right: -20px;
      background: #fff;
      margin-top: -5px;
      padding-left: 25px;
      padding-top: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      width: 100%;
    }
```